# Names relegating a sefer to Shemos

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, shemos-sacred-names

Which names, other than the tetragrammaton relegate a sefer to shemos?

In particular, is shadai one of those names?

Answer (score 3):

Shakai is one of the names that requires placement in shemos.

To quote an [article by the KOF-K](http://www.shaimos.org/Desposing%20of%20Shaimos%20by%20the%20KOF-K.pdf) (second page there):

> Those names are: שם הויה, אדנות, א-ל, א-לוה, אל-והים, ש-די, צבאות. a<sup>9</sup>
>
> <sup>9</sup> Refer to Mesechtas Shavuos [35a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=26&daf=35&format=pdf)-35b, Tur Y.D. 276, Shulchan Aruch 276:9, Bais Yosef. Some say אהיה אשר אהיה (Shulchan Aruch ibid).

The Gemara that they quoted (Mesechtas Shavuos [35a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=26&daf=35&format=pdf)-35b) says (in part):

> אלו הן שמות שאין נמחקין כגון אל אלהיך אלהים אלהיכם אהיה אשר אהיה אלף
>   דלת ויוד הי **שדי** צבאות הרי אלו **אין נמחקין**
>
> These are names that are not allowed to be
>   erased: *kel*.....**shakai**, [and] *tzevakos* **may not be erased**.

Comment: Are tz'vaot and elokim based on context when they refer to the KB"H?

Comment: I believe so, thought can't source that (yet). I learned from my rebbeim that you actually *should* read the phrase "elohim acheirim" as such, so as not to lend extra respect to those "other gods" that we do not, in actuality, respect.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Couldn't find anything easily....you could try [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) though ;)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/34633/5323) may be relevant.

Comment: "א-ל, א-לוה, אל-והים" Why only by Elohim does the dash not go between the Alef and Lamed?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know but that's a direct quote; ask the KOF-K